Prisma / tRPC + MongoDB error in AWS Lambda
I have an app that uses a tRPC server, connected to MongoDB using Prisma as an ORM. It is deployed as an AWS Lambda function. When querying my 'engagements' collection, I was returned with this error:
[{
    "error": {
        "message": "\nInvalid `prisma.engagement.findMany()` invocation:\n\n\nInconsistent query result: Field provider is required to return data, got `null` instead.",
        "code": -32603,
        "data": {
            "code": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR",
            "httpStatus": 500,
            "stack": "PrismaClientUnknownRequestError: \nInvalid `prisma.engagement.findMany()` invocation:\n\n\nInconsistent query result: Field provider is required to return data, got `null` instead.\n    at ni.handleRequestError (/deps/7ff9aebb-6d47-4d1b-83c7-7897efd7b0b7/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:124:6989)\n    at ni.handleAndLogRequestError (/deps/7ff9aebb-6d47-4d1b-83c7-7897efd7b0b7/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:124:6206)\n    at ni.request (/deps/7ff9aebb-6d47-4d1b-83c7-7897efd7b0b7/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:124:5926)\n    at u (/deps/7ff9aebb-6d47-4d1b-83c7-7897efd7b0b7/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:129:10023)\n    at <anonymous> (/private/var/folders/dm/3qghyfj90ms6jkp3p4284c_r0000gn/T/tmpsehwqwof/trpc.ts:287:20)\n    at u8.middlewares (/deps/7ff9aebb-6d47-4d1b-83c7-7897efd7b0b7/node_modules/@trpc/server/dist/index.mjs:420:30)\n    at i (/deps/7ff9aebb-6d47-4d1b-83c7-7897efd7b0b7/node_modules/@trpc/server/dist/index.mjs:456:32)\n    at i (/deps/7ff9aebb-6d47-4d1b-83c7-7897efd7b0b7/node_modules/@trpc/server/dist/index.mjs:456:32)\n    at H (/deps/7ff9aebb-6d47-4d1b-83c7-7897efd7b0b7/node_modules/@trpc/server/dist/index.mjs:486:24)\n    at O4H (/deps/7ff9aebb-6d47-4d1b-83c7-7897efd7b0b7/node_modules/@trpc/server/dist/resolveHTTPResponse-cd1a9112.mjs:46:22)",
            "path": "getPendingPreEngagements"
        }
    }
}]

Relevant chunk from my tRPC appRouter code:
  getPendingPreEngagements: privateProcedure.query(async ({ ctx }) => {
    console.log("getPendingPreEngagements");

    if (!ctx.isSuperUser) {
      throw new TRPCError({ message: "Unauthorized", code: "UNAUTHORIZED" });
    }
    const result = await ctx.prisma.engagement.findMany({
      where: {
        status: {
          in: [
            "PreEngagementFlaggedForReview",
            "ApplicationSubmitted",
            "PreEngagementRejected",
            "ReportStarted",
          ],
        },
      },
      orderBy: { preEngagement: { fields: { created_at: "desc" } } },
      include: {
        provider: {
          include: { org: true },
        },
      },
    });
    return result.filter((a) => !a.preEngagement.approval_type);
  }),

The output of 'npm ls prisma' locally:
elicensing-prisma@1.0.0 /Users/julien/Developer/elicensing-prisma
├─┬ @prisma/client@5.6.0
│ └── prisma@5.6.0 deduped
└── prisma@5.6.0

npm ls '@prisma/client':
elicensing-prisma@1.0.0 /Users/julien/Developer/elicensing-prisma
└── @prisma/client@5.6.0

And in the tRPC dir:
hello_world@1.0.0 /Users/julien/Developer/elicensing/trpc/api
├─┬ @prisma/client@5.6.0
│ └── prisma@5.6.0 deduped
└── prisma@5.6.0

hello_world@1.0.0 /Users/julien/Developer/elicensing/trpc/api
└── @prisma/client@5.6.0

I am using node v18, prisma v5.6.0, and @trpc/server v10.43.3
I tried to replicate this locally using this code, separate from the tRPC function:
const { PrismaClient } = require('@prisma/client');
const fs = require('fs');

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

async function getPendingPreEngagements() {
  console.log("getPendingPreEngagements");

  try {
    const result = await prisma.engagement.findMany({
      where: {
        status: {
          in: [
            "PreEngagementFlaggedForReview",
            "ApplicationSubmitted",
            "PreEngagementRejected",
            "ReportStarted",
          ],
        },
      },
      orderBy: { preEngagement: { fields: { created_at: "desc" } } },
      include: {
        provider: {
          include: { org: true },
        },
      },
    });

    return result.filter((a) => !a.preEngagement.approval_type);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error:", error);
  } finally {
    await prisma.$disconnect();
  }
}

async function main() {
  const filteredResult = await getPendingPreEngagements();
  fs.writeFileSync('pendingPreEngagements.json', JSON.stringify(filteredResult, null, 2));
}

main()

I encountered the same issue locally, until I downgraded both 'prisma' and '@prisma/client' from 6.1.0 to 5.6.0. Since then, the issue disappeared and I could successfully pull engagements.
I tried to replicate this in the tRPC server by deleting the node_modules folder and changing the prisma and @prisma/client versions in package.json from "^5.6.0" to just "5.6.0" like I did with the separate function. I built and deployed the server using AWS SAM, but I am still encountering the same issue.
I checked the code from the AWS SAM build folder and it only refers to prisma version 5.6.0 as it should.
If anybody has any suggestions as to why the Lambda function is behaving like this then please let me know! Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!
